# register service worker in ASP.net react app for progressive web app

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, asp.net-core-3.0

As a toy project, I created a react web app with create-react-app. I then changed "serviceworker.unregister()" to "serviceworker.register()" in index.js. The toy project is on Github here: https://github.com/verybadcat/CreateReactAppPwa. I then tried Google's lighthouse audits via two different ways of launching the app.

If I launched it with "npm start", lighthouse was unhappy about several things. The three that interest me at the moment are the following:

```
Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline
start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline
Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url
```

It also complained that I wasn't using https. I want to put that aside for now.

On the other hand, if I launched it via "npm run build" and copied the url from that command into my browser, lighthouse complained about https only.

Now for the real project. The real project is a netcoreapp3.0 react app. At the moment, it is essentially Microsoft's template project. It has a file index.js which looks like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement);

// Uncomment the line above that imports the registerServiceWorker function
// and the line below to register the generated service worker.
// By default create-react-app includes a service worker to improve the
// performance of the application by caching static assets. This service
// worker can interfere with the Identity UI, so it is
// disabled by default when Identity is being used.
//
registerServiceWorker();
```

The registerServiceWorker call that I uncommented goes to a file from the default project that looks like this:

````
export default function register () {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);
      } else {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}```
````

The problem is that in every case I've tried, the behavior is the same as the "debug" version of the toy app. This includes both a debug and a release build of the project. Lighthouse does not appear to see the service worker. I see two things that I can speculate might be the problem, but I really don't know:

1. I'm doing everything on localhost. The register file has a check for localhost and different behavior if we are on localhost.
2. The folder structure is different from the toy app. In the toy app, index.js and index.html are in the same folder. In the real app, index.js is in a folder "src" while index.html is in a folder "public". Both "src" and "public" are children of the same parent. BUT it's not clear how this might be changed as I remember seeing a doc that index.js should have that exact filename and path, and if I try to import something outside of the folder, I get an error saying that imports outside of the folder are not supported.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I am also trying to do the same. No luck yet